# My puppy at some dish soap mixed with water, is she OK/ what should I do/ what will happen (symptoms)?

Tags: dogs, health, safety

My puppy ate some dish soap mixed with water in the form of bubbles, is she ok or what are the symptoms of this?

Answer (score 1):

The severity of problems depends on how much was consumed, how diluted it was, and what brand soap was involved. And, of course, how big your pup is. [Dawn Dish Soap](https://dawn-dish.com/en-us/dawn-faqs/dish-soap-safety) recommends (people) drink additional water (which is probably going to be difficult to get a puppy to do). But some soaps are more dangerous than others. 
More on the subject:
[Detergent Poisoning in Dogs](https://wagwalking.com/condition/detergent-poisoning)
[A Similar Question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/909/what-harm-will-soap-water-do-to-my-dog)