# My dog drank alot of laundry run off water should i worry?

Tags: health, poison, large-dogs

He has been drinking the water quite often without me noticing and is throwing up and dry heaving alot and i dont know what to do i cant afford to go to the vet! What can i do for him?

Comment: Call a local vet or an emergency clinic and ask for advice.Pplease be aware that it might be better for your dog if you give it up for adoption if you can not properly care for it.

Comment: this question is the same as yours https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/909/what-harm-will-soap-water-do-to-my-dog?rq=1 the answers are the same as to your question.

Comment: From what i have read it most likely has detergent poisoning and i recommend you reading this https://wagwalking.com/condition/detergent-poisoning

Answer (score 0):

Why is your dog allowed access to the laundry run off? You need to monitor the area while doing laundry if you truly care about your dog. Make sure you Are providing your dog with fresh water.